# exactly represent Dirac distribution as derivatives of continuous function

Tags: distribution-theory

It seems that in Rudin's functional analysis (P168, Thm6.27) that the Dirac distribution $\delta_0$ on $R^1$ can write as
$$
 \delta_0=f_0+f'_1+f''_2,
$$
for $\{f_i\}_{i=0}^2\in C(R^1)$, there $'$ should be understand as derivative of distruibution of course.

My problem is, can we write down $f_i$ exactly?

Comment: The answer is yes. Probably you know a locally integrable function, whose derivative is $\delta_0$? And maybe you can "integrate" this function again? It is not difficult.

Comment: The user has asked this question twice; see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081414/represent-dirac-distruibution-as-a-combination-of-derivatives-of-continuous-func).

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thanks, it is caused by the post button not working properly when I try to submit my question. Maybe any someone can merge this two post?