# Represent Dirac distruibution as a combination of derivatives of continuous functions?

Tags: distribution-theory

It seems from Rudin's *functional analysis* (P168, Thm6.27), the Dirac distribution $\delta_0$ on $R^1$ can be written as
$$
 \delta_0=f_0+f'_1+f''_2,
$$
for $\{f_i\}_{i=0}^2\in C(R^1)$, there $'$ should be understand as derivative of distruibution of course.

My problem is, can we write down $f_i$ exactly?

The Dirac distribution is defined as
$$
 \delta_0(\phi)=\phi(0),\quad\phi\in C_0^\infty(R)
$$

Comment: One half of the second derivative of $|x|$.

Comment: @paulgarrett exactly!

Comment: @paulgarrett In fact, I am a litter confused in calculating $f_2(x)=|x|$'s distribution derivative, why $f_2'(0)=0$?

Comment: The first derivative of $|x|$ does not have a pointwise value at $0$. The best way to verify here is to compute $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi''(x)\,|x|/2\;dx$ for a test function $\varphi$, and see that this does indeed yield $\varphi(0)$.

Comment: @paulgarrett Any reason or reference for this( $|x|'$ is not a function anymore)?

Comment: I would certainly say that $|x|'$ is a "function", despite the fact that it does not meet the supposedly-official requirement that it produce an output for every input. At worst, it is a "generalized function" in the sense of L. Schwartz, Gelfand, et al, meaning that it can be _integrated_ _against_ test functions, at least, regardless of issues of pointwise values. Note that the computation of the integral against $\varphi''$ does not need any assignment of value at $0$ to $|x|'$.

Comment: @paulgarrett A bit late in the day, but I'm coming at this from the Treves book on distributions, and he presents the same problem. However, his terminology makes it very clear he isn't talking about pseudofunctions. Therefore, I don't think this is on point in terms of the question as set.

Comment: @MarkoStojovic, I'm confused about the sense of "pseudofunction" in your comment: how can Dirac delta be obtained as a derivative of anything at all if we're not talking about distributional derivatives? Maybe I misunderstand your point.

Comment: @paulgarrett As I'm learning, I'm very much a slave of the text I'm using - Treves - so apols if it comes across as rigid. Treves is uncharacteristically explicit in calling a distribution a 'function' iff it is locally integrable. He then defines pseudofunctions (in passing) as functions whose product with a test function *that vanishes in a neighbourhood of zero* is integrable (p.224-225).  Why this is relevant to me here is because he later sets an exercise that specifically asks for a solution in terms of continuous functions. I replicated that here yesterday as question 4822290.

Comment: Reflecting on this a bit more, he seems to be using the term 'pseudofunction' as a way of  presenting, as a distribution, a function that is not integrable in a neighbourhood of zero. The 'pseudo' prefix then warns the 'user' to only attempt to apply the distribution based* on such a function to test functions that vanish around zero. I hope that makes sense.  Treves doesn't provide a concise definition. (*A 'distribution based on a function' here just means a distribution defined as the integral of the product of such a function and an arbitrary test function.)

Comment: This is a little idiosyncratic... (But, also, I'd imagine that he was treating a special case, of distributions that are locally $L^1$ _except_ at $0$, and for _them_ he defines "pseudo-function"...)